# Some examples or sources for apache wicket with scala?

Tags: scala, wicket

Someone know sources, projects, tutorials or books that cover apache wicket with scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JavaZone-conferences previous submit application was written with the combo. You'll find the source here https://github.com/javaBin/submitit and a talk given on the subject here http://video.javazone.no/talk/46284273.